# Multivariable integral limitation proof

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

Please prove the following formula.
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\cdots\int_0^1 \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}dx_1\cdots dx_n = 2
$$

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Alizter Yes. I tried to interpret the left hand side of the given formula as $E[1/Z_n]$, where $Z_n = \frac{\sum X_i}{n}$, and then use central limit theorem and the notion of delta function. But I don't think my solution is not exact, so I want 'rigid' one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\cdots\int_{0}^{1}
     {n \over \sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i}}\dd x_{1}\ldots\dd x_{n} = 2}$

> \begin{align}&\int_{0}^{1}\cdots\int_{0}^{1}
> {n \over \sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i}}\dd x_{1}\ldots\dd x_{n}
> =n\int_{0}^{1}\cdots\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-t\sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i}}
> \,\dd t\,\dd x_{1}\ldots\dd x_{n}
> \\[3mm]&=n\int_{0}^{\infty}\pars{\int_{0}^{1}\expo{-tx}\,\dd x}^{n}\,\dd t
> =n\int_{0}^{\infty}\pars{1 - \expo{-t} \over t}^{n}\,\dd t\end{align}

Can you take it from here ?.

It seems that the integrand behaves as $\ds{\expo{-nt/2}}$ when $\ds{n \gg 1}$ since $\ds{{1 - \expo{-t} \over t} \sim\pars{1 - {t \over2}}}$ when $\ds{t \sim 0}$.  The main contribution comes from $\ds{t \gtrsim 0}$. That integral and limit was posted recently.

Comment: Thank you for your time! WHY "the main contribution comes from ..." ?

Comment: @dazaga I did some plots for increasing values of $n$. I saw the integrand goes to zero "very fast" as soon as we increase $t$ ( for $n \gg 1$ ). I think it can be show analytically. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** [Assuming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) that, as *n* grows larger and larger, the sequence $x_i$ becomes more [equidistributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence), then the sum in the denominator will also draw closer and closer to a certain well-known [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula#Examples).

Comment: Thank you for your answering! Is my interpretation posted above right?